# Present a Modal from the View Model of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController`, that as a ViewModel class. I am trying to build out my application using the **MVVM** pattern.

My tableView has a cell that display an image, that image has a gesture recogniser that calls a method in the view model on press.

At this point I would like to present a `ViewController` modally, with some embedded content.

However my `TableView cell` conforms to `UITableViewCell` so I cannot call present from here.

My ViewModel does not conform to anything, so I cannot call present from there either.

How can I trigger a modal to appear, from within a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: MVVM needs implementing observers. If you're using MVVM without any observers and binding it's not MVVM. Just simply trigger a single notification from cell view model to your controller or any generic view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of options but I will cover solution with delegate.

The idea is to define `protocol` and property of that protocol in `MyViewModel` and make `MyViewController` conforming to it.

Here is how the `MyViewModel` could look like:

```
protocol MyViewModelDelegate: class {
    func didTapOnCell()
}

class MyViewModel {
    // Please note the delegate is weak and optional
    weak var delegate: MyViewModelDelegate?

    // This function handle gesture recognizer taps
    @objc func handleImageViewTap() {
        delegate?.didTapOnCell()
    }

    // Here is the rest of the ViewModel class...
}
```

Then in the `MyViewController` you set viewModel's delegate property to `self` and conforms to the protocol function (I'm assuming view controller references the view model instance).

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

    func setup() {
        // ...
        // When MyViewModel is initialised, set the delegate property to self
        myViewModel.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyViewController: ViewModelDelegate {
    func didTapOnCell() {
        // ...
        // Allocate instance of anotherViewController here and present it
        self.present(anotherViewController, animated: true, completion: .none)
    }
}
```

This way you can let know `MyViewController` something happened in `MyViewModel` and act accordingly.

Please note it's necessary to make `delegate` property optional to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Add a UIWindow extension

extension UIWindow {

```
static var top: UIViewController? {
    get {
        return topViewController()
    }
}

static var root: UIViewController? {
    get {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    }
}

static func topViewController(from viewController: UIViewController? = UIWindow.root) -> UIViewController? {
    if let tabBarViewController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        return topViewController(from: tabBarViewController.selectedViewController)
    } else if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(from: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    } else if let presentedViewController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(from: presentedViewController)
    } else {
        return viewController
    }
}
```

}

than call this from anywhere like:

```
    guard let topController = UIWindow.top else  { return } // UIWindow.root
    let youVC = theStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
    youVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    youVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    topController.present(youVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```